# div issue in html in all browser

Tags: html, css

I have two html code. In first code background is not coming. But In second code when i put **clear:both;**  code then background is coming. Can you have any alternative easy option to show background instead of height. I dont want to put height and extra div structure.

First Code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-    transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<!-- please dont use height in background -->
<body>
<div style="background:#990000;">
<div style="float:left;">left part</div>
<div style="float:right">right part</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Second Code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<!-- please dont use height in background -->
<body>
<div style="background:#990000;">
<div style="float:left;">left part</div>
<div style="float:right">right part</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Your kind revert shall be highly appriciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: ... why don't you want to put height? That's the best and easiest way to do this. (*See proof-of-concept [(1)](http://jsfiddle.net/eMt7b/) and [(2)](http://jsfiddle.net/eMt7b/1/).*)

Comment: because i donot want to fix height. i need auto height on it. if i put hight then if i want to increase page lenght then every time i have to go in css and change height. SO i want some alt.

Comment: 100% is not "fixed". Did you look at my proofs of concept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi now there are many option clear to parent div if you used floating

as like this  **first  is**

```
.mainclear{
background:#990000;
}

.mainclear:after{
content:'';
  clear:both;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:block;
}
```

**secound is**

```
.mainclear{
background:#990000;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

**your html code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-    transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<!-- please dont use height in background -->
<body>
<div class="mainclear">
<div style="float:left;">left part</div>
<div style="float:right">right part</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

***[Demo first](http://tinkerbin.com/RiUIus3m)***

---------\

***[Demo Second](http://tinkerbin.com/w1SXx16d)***

Comment: if u can used to first method this is work all latest browser ie+8 if you chose second method it work all browser ie+6  ... and all latest browser

Comment: @Vinay depand on you layout if you are using latest browser ignore ie7 than used to first .......

Comment: <style>
.mainclear{
background:#990000;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-align:left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="mainclear">
<div style="float:left; height:50px; background:#999900;">Demo Text Demo text<br />
<br />
Demo Text Demo text<br />
Demo Text <br />
Demo Text Demo text<br />
Demo Text <br />
Demo Text Demo text<br />
Demo Text <br />
Demo Text Demo text<br />
Demo Text
</div>
<div style="float:right; height:150px; background:#006633;">right part</div>
</div>
From this code text is hidden. so this is not useful

Comment: @Vinay remove to hight on your left div demo http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/ArKyx/9/

Answer (score 1):

Please Try  code given below

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-    transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<!-- please dont use height in background -->
 <body>
 <div style="background-color:#999000;overflow:hidden;">
        <div style="float:left;">left part</div>
        <div style="float:right">right part</div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Add `overflow:hidden`. It will be work.

thanks

Comment: i put inner div height in px then text is hide
<style> .mainclear{ background:#990000; overflow:hidden; text-align:left; } </style> </head> <body> <div class="mainclear"> <div style="float:left; height:50px; background:#999900;">Demo Text Demo text<br /> <br /> Demo Text Demo text<br /> Demo Text <br /> Demo Text Demo text<br /> Demo Text <br /> Demo Text Demo text<br /> Demo Text <br /> Demo Text Demo text<br /> Demo Text </div> <div style="float:right; height:150px; background:#006633;">right part</div> </div> <!-- From this code text is hidden. so this is not useful -->

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:auto` to the parent div

```
<div style="background:#990000; overflow:auto">
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/VjXen/1/)

Comment: why you use auto. If we use hidden code is also run. What is the concept of auto.

Comment: If you give height in px for any of the inner div then overflow:hidden will hide the excess content whereas overflow:auto extends the outer div according to the height of the inner div.

Comment: <style> .mainclear{ background:#990000; overflow:auto; text-align:left; } </style> </head> <body> <div class="mainclear"> <div style="float:left; height:50px; background:#999900;">Demo Text Demo text<br /> <br /> Demo Text Demo text<br /> Demo Text <br /> Demo Text Demo text<br /> Demo Text <br /> Demo Text Demo text<br /> Demo Text <br /> Demo Text Demo text<br /> Demo Text </div> <div style="float:right; height:150px; background:#006633;">right part</div> </div> <!-- From this code text is hidden. so this is not useful -->